# How to update date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

SO basically I'm trying to update my records in my table via jdbc driver, The jdbc driver won't let me to update any records, it is constantly throwing this error message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'set brand ='Nissan', set type='Compactor Vehicle',set model='zx1000x',set dateAq' at line 1

I've check all the values and they seems to be in the same format as for the sql. I suspect that it is the date records which is not making it.

Below is the sql syntax that I'm using

```
update vehicles set capacity = "+capacity+",set brand ='"+brand+"', set type='"+type+"',set model='"+model+"',set dateAqcuire ="+date+" where registrationPlate ='"+registrationNumber+"'
```

```
public void updateVehicle(){
database db = new database();
String registrationNumber = RegistrationPlate.getText();
int vehicleCapacity = Integer.parseInt(capacity.getText());
String brandz= brand.getText();
String vehicletype = vehicleType.getValue();
String vehicleModel = Model.getText();
LocalDate localDate= dateAccquire.getValue();
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
db.UpdateVehicle(registrationNumber, vehicleCapacity, brandz, vehicletype, vehicleModel, date);
vehicleAlerts("updated");
}
```

and below is the method signature

```
public void UpdateVehicle(String registrationNumber,int capacity,String brand,String type,String model,java.sql.Date date){//code to update records}
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: The date value needs to be quoted.

Comment: I guess `dateAqcuire` should probably be `dateAcquire`. But, as already said, you definitely need prepared statements: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Do **NOT** concatenate values into a SQL string like that. Please learn how to use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @Turophile you answer help thanks :)

Comment: Thanks to all it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set keyword only one:

```
update vehicles set capacity = "+capacity+",brand ='"+brand+"', type='"+type+" ..
```

Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: hehe yes i'll take a look in that later, and also date should be quoted :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `SET` every time before each column, just use `SET` keyword once.

```
update vehicles 
set capacity = "+capacity+", 
    brand ='"+brand+"', 
    type='"+type+"', 
    model='"+model+"', 
    dateAqcuire ="+date+" 
where registrationPlate ='"+registrationNumber+"'
```

**General Syntax:**
The syntax for the MariaDB UPDATE statement when updating one table is:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
[WHERE conditions]
[ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ]]
[LIMIT number_rows];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Set Keyword once and set Date in Quotes.

```
update vehicles 
set capacity = "+capacity+", 
    brand ='"+brand+"', 
    type='"+type+"', 
    model='"+model+"', 
    dateAqcuire ='"+date+"'
where registrationPlate ='"+registrationNumber+"'
```